# React-native Integrating with Existing Apps is too slow in Android

Tags: android, performance, react-native

I already built a Android App by normal way, but now for business, I need intergrating react native in my App for some Views.
when I click the amazing icon from Home View to ReactNative part, the loading time is too long, and there is a black background showed first.

I already closed debug mode, and bundle the js part by --dev false option.

If there better solution to open the activity faster or improve the render performance.

If there is a way to render or load react-native in background when I open the APP is also nice.

Think you very much.

Comment: if you want to load larger size image use this : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. iOS takes 2 sec to load the RN bit of the app. Any ideas?